# display element (span tag ) after last ocurence of repeated item inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to display something like this inside an ng-repeat: display a span tag saying the total purchase right after the last purchase of each person.( I do not want to display the total after each purchase). I have an array of object like this :

```
   let group=[{name:'Brandon Pack',city:'NY',purchase:25,accepted:true},
   {name:'Josh Vilet',city:'Memphis',purchase:30,accepted:true},
    {name:'Brandon Pack',city:'NY',purchase:62,accepted:true},
    {name:'Patrick Whiteside',city:'NY',purchase:50,accepted:false},
    {name:'Josh Vilet',city:'Memphis',purchase:50,accepted:true}]
```

I can get the total, my problem is with the view that I don't want to display the total only after the last ocurence for that person

Comment: A jsfiddle example would be helpful to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can create a function in your controller in order to get the total amount:

```
$scope.getTotal = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $scope.group.forEach(function(customer){
        sum += customer.purchase;
    });
    return sum;
}
```

By the way, you can't declare variables with whitespaces in their name, like "let group", better call it "letGroup".

Then, you just have to create your table in Html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Purchase</th>
            <th>Accepted</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="o in group">
            <td ng-bind="o.name"></td>
            <td ng-bind="o.city"></td>
            <td ng-bind="o.purchase"></td>
            <td ng-bind="o.accepted ? 'Yes': 'No'"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td ng-bind="getTotal()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```